# List all pages including archive

Tags: get-posts, wp-list-pages, php

I'm creating a custom options page on my site.
One of the options is controlling a box on the homepage and i'm trying to set the link for the item to any page on the site via a `select` menu.

as of now I can list all the pages including my custom post types - what I'm trying to do is also have the custom post type archive page as a link as well as some sort of ordering in the list.

So for example the select hierarchy should be something like this:
Work - (Custom Post Type Archive) 
  Matchbox - (Custom Post Type Page)
Page - (Regular Page)

My current code:

```
$sitePages= get_posts(array('post_type'=>array('page', 'work', 'people'), 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'depth'=> 0));

$wp_cats = array();
foreach ($sitePages as $page_list ) {
       $wp_cats[$page_list->ID] = $page_list->post_title;
}
array_unshift($wp_cats, " ");
```

and then a foreach on `$wp_cats` calls it back.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

*****UPDATE***
Based on [Sven's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125725/35799) ∨∨

I used the following code to output everything.

```
<select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
        <option value="">Choose A Page</option>
        <?php 
        $post_types = array( 'page', 'work', 'people' );
        $wp_cats = array();
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

        $pages = get_pages( array( 'post_type'=>$post_type, 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'depth'=> 0 ) );

        $obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
        // output custom post type archive with link
        if ( $post_type !== 'page' ){
        echo '<option value="' . get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) .'"';
        if (get_option( $value['id'] ) == get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type )) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }
        echo '>'. $obj->labels->singular_name . '</option>';
        }
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
       $wp_cats[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
       // output posts with link
       echo '<option value="' . get_permalink($page->ID).'" ';
       if (get_option( $value['id'] ) == get_permalink($page->ID)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }
       echo '>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $page->post_title .'</option>';
         }
       }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is definitely possible. Grab your post types and insert them in `$post_types` to loop through every one of them to manually generate the archives and posts:

```
<?php
// post types of your choice
$post_types = array( 'page', 'work', 'people' );

$wp_cats = array();
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

    $pages = get_pages( array( 'post_type'=>$post_type, 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'depth'=> 0 ) );

    $obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    // output custom post type archive with link
    echo '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) . '">' . $obj->labels->singular_name . '</a><br />';

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
       $wp_cats[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
       // output posts with link
       echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Note: As you can see this will output plain links; I think you can easily adjust the HTML-markup yourself as you didn't request something special in your question.

You can also auto-generate the structure via [wp_list_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages), but this is sometimes getting tricky if you'll need a custom HTML-markup:

```
<?php
// post types of your choice
$post_types = array( 'page', 'work', 'people' );

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    // generate complete list links and titles
    wp_list_pages( array( 'post_type'=>$post_type, 'title_li'=>$post_type ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank You! I ended up going with the first option and outputted it into a `<select>`